# Write bold \delta

Tags: symbols

Is it possible to insert delta but not in math mode? I have

```
\def\Name{text ...}
```

where text include \delta. This \Name is in displayed in bold and in plain and \delta in math mode can be only one of them. 
Thank you

I need to write delta in a way \textbf make it bold. I can't use \bm in math mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\textbf{text $\delta$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why `\delta` should not to be in math mode? please provide an *mwe* (minimal working example) from which we can see what you like to have.

Comment: Is it possible to write symbol `$\delta $` in another way? Not in math mode.

Comment: I need it as a part of text that sould be bold in some places and plain in some places and \delta can be bold or plain, not both

Comment: $\delta$ for normal face and &\boldsymbol{\delta}$ for boldface. needed `amsmath` package

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: try `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textbf{text $\boldsymbol{\delta}$ and some more text in boldface}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\textdelta`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\newcommand{\Name}{text\textdelta text}

\begin{document}

\Name

\textbf{\Name}

\textit{\Name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you have more possibilities:

- with `amsmath` package

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
  \textbf{text $\boldsymbol{\delta}$ and some more text in boldface}
  \end{document}
  ```
- with `bm` package:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \begin{document}
  \textbf{text $\bm{\delta}$ and some more text in boldface}
  \end{document}
  ```

  in both cases you will get a similar result:

[image]

- with `bm` package and normal boldface text:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \begin{document}
  text $\bm{\delta}$ and some more text
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I have a problem that I need to use `{text $\bm{\delta}$ and some more text in boldface}` in bold and not in bold and delta will be still bold. I need this because of a template

Comment: @LukášAltman, sorry, your question is not clear.  according to your comment you need only omit `\textbf{`

Comment: @Zarko The question specifies that it should be possible to include the delta somehow in the custom `\Name` command, and that afterwards the complete contents of that command (including delta) should be able to be printed in plain text as well as in boldface. That does not work when the delta in isolation needs to be surrounded by `$\bm{}$` or `$\boldsymbol{}$` or anything in every individual case where it needs to be bold.

Comment: @DennisSoemers, than -- according to your interpretation -- i not understand question. not happen the first time :-). seems that other solution than better suit what op like to have. however, i'm still convinced, that my solution is the simplest and can be implement also in `\Name`. op will decide, what he more prefer ...

Answer (score 5):

One can always use *real* Greek. `\delta` is only the math mode version.

```
\documentclass[margin=2]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand\mydelta{\foreignlanguage{greek}{δ}}
\def\Name{text \mydelta}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\Name} \textit{\Name} \Name
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very clever one:

```
\boldsymbol{\delta}
```